# Put a PL/SQL block cursor result on a php variable

Tags: php, oracle

I need to put the query cursor result on a PHP variable.
The result of select is a number that I need to use later.
Is there any way to do this? ( I'm using oracle 11g )

```
$query2 = "DECLARE
CURSOR cursore IS
SELECT example FROM etable FOR UPDATE of example;
BEGIN
  OPEN cursore;
FETCH cursore INTO v_consulta;
UPDATE etable SET example = example + 1;
COMMIT;
  CLOSE cursore;
END;";
```

---

With this query I need to select a column, get its value and put it in a variable PHP. And then I need to lock it to prevent concurrent queries from getting the same value before the update. This was the best way that I have found. But I can't take the result of the select.

---

Following is the whole code with FETCH and `oci_bind_by_name`

```
<?php

    include "config.php";    
    $query2 = "DECLARE
    CURSOR cursore IS
    SELECT example FROM etable FOR UPDATE of example;
    BEGIN
      OPEN cursore;
    FETCH cursore INTO v_consulta;
    UPDATE etable SET example = example + 1;
    COMMIT;
      CLOSE cursore;
    END;";

    $s2 = oci_parse($c, $query2);
    if (!$s2) {
        $m2 = oci_error($c);
        trigger_error('Could not parse statement: ' . $m['message'], E_USER_ERROR);
    } //prepara para a execução

    $r2 = oci_execute($s2);
    if (!$r2){
        $m2 = oci_error($s2);
        trigger_error('Could not execute statement: ' . $m['message'], E_USER_ERROR);
    }// executa a consulta

while (oci_fetch($s2)) {
    echo oci_result($s2, 'v_consulta');
}

?>
```

---

I need to take the value of the FETCH and put ir in a PHP variable.
Is it possible?
Maybe there is another way of doing the query.
( I'm using oracle 11g ).

I get this error:

```
Warning: oci_fetch(): ORA-24374: define not done before fetch or execute and fetch in C:\xampp\htdocs\ProjectO\numorca.php on line 30
```

line 30 is:

```
while (oci_fetch($s2)) {
    echo oci_result($s2, 'v_consulta');
}
```

---

Is anyone able to help out with this request? Thanks.

Comment: So, I don't know all the ins and outs of a cursor, and as such, I decided to start from the beginning. I found this video https://youtu.be/RHRjLd0bEaQ?t=515. The link goes directly to the section that is talking about saving to a variable. Maybe this can help you.

Comment: Your PL/SQL statement isn't fetching any rows, which I don't think is what you intended. Add in the FETCH and see if that helps.

Comment: @Boneist with this query I need to select a column, get its value and add in a php variable, lock it,  and then update to prevent two concurrent queries from getting the same value. This was the best way I found to do this. Do you know another way? I do not know what else to search.

Comment: You have opened a cursor (which means, effectively "work out the best path to get this data". You haven't done anything to retrieve the data, though. Working with explicit cursors in Oracle goes something like this: "Open cursor. Fetch row(s) from cursor. Close cursor". You have the Open and Close cursor steps, but you have simply failed to fetch any data. I'm no php coder, but I think that's probably a large part of your problem. I suggest you look up how to fetch from a cursor.

Comment: You gave me a light on what to look for. Thank you!

Comment: I think you might want to use a **sequence**, which is an oracle feature for counting up and getting unique IDs.

Comment: `FETCH` the cursor `INTO` a placeholder variable `?` then *bind* a PHP variable to that plaeholder. Sorry no code as I'm in a rush but hope this gives you a pointer.

Comment: Hey @Adder I searched for sequences, and that would be exactly what I needed. However, the database is shared with other programs that have been using this column for some time. This number would be the next budget to be made by a seller, this makes the sequence must always be increasing and can not be lost. With sequences If there is a fault in the system, all sequential numbering will be lost.

Comment: If you can make the other programs use the sequence too, it would good. If other programs use the next + 1 method and you cannot change them, I guess you would be stuck with workarounds. These workarounds might be unsafe.

Comment: @Adder I can't change them. I have no control over them and I do not manage the database. I need a solution that could be implemented only within my application. Thank you very mutch i will search more and see if we can implement this later in the other aplications. But for now I can't

Comment: @TenGI did as you advised me, but the way I did, I can not print the variable. Could you suggest me another way? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to select a column, get its value and put it in a variable php

in posgresql you can 'UPDATE [...] RETURNING [...]' and avoid cursor:

```
pg_query($dbconn, 'BEGIN TRANSACTION;');

pg_send_query($dbconn,'UPDATE etable SET example = example + 1 RETURNING example;');
$res = pg_get_result($dbconn);
$array = pg_fetch_assoc($res);
echo 'example=' . $array['example'] . "\n";
pg_query($dbconn, 'COMMIT;');
```

Between "BEGIN TRANSACTION" and "COMMIT" nobody could select/update/delete `etable`, so it could be a bottle neck.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but this query returns the column after the update. I need the value of it before the change, and only when I get this number the update can be done.